# Finding the number of occurences of a sub-string in a string without using library functions

Tags: python, string

I have to do this exercise without using library function. So far I have reached here:-

```
string = input("Enther The String :")
substring = input("Enter the substring :") 
count = 0
for i in range(len(string)):
    if string[i:i+len(substring)] == substring:
        if string[i+len(substring)] == ' ':
            count += 1
        else:
            count = 0
print(count)
```

But, let us say if the sub-string is 'bob' and the string is 'bob cat bob cat bobs cat', the program still counts 'bob' in 'bobs' and I don't want that. Also this code always returns 0. Please help! Thanks!

Comment: Can you use `split()`?

Comment: No, we can not use it.

Comment: What should be the count for something like `'bobob'`?

Comment: So you don't want to count substrings, you want to count word occurences.

Comment: Yes, I basically want to count the word occurrences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you're allowed to use slicing, so you can use that to check whether the character before/after the substring is a space or empty string, if it is then increment count by 1. Note that slices never raise exception, even for out of range indices.

```
def sub_str_count(s, sub_str):
    le = len(sub_str)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:i+le] == sub_str and s[i-1:i] in ('', ' ') and \
                                                       s[i+le:i+le+1] in ('', ' '):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Exception handling based version of the above code:

```
def check(s, ind):
    """
    Check whether the item present at this index is a space or not.
    For out of bound indices return True.
    For negative indices return True.
    """

    if ind < 0:
        return True
    try:
        return s[ind] == ' '
    except IndexError:
        return True

def sub_str_count(s, sub_str):
    le = len(sub_str)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:i+le] == sub_str and check(s, i-1) and check(s, i+le):
            count += 1
    return count
```

Comment: Not familiar with 'try.'

Comment: @VedantGanjoo It is used for [exception handling](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Comment: Can we do it without that?

Comment: @VedantGanjoo Look carefully, I've posted two solutions in my answer. :)

Comment: def sub_str_count(s, sub_str):
    le = len(sub_str)
    count = 0
    for i in range(len(s)):
        if s[i:i+le] == sub_str and s[i-1:i] in ('', ' ') and \
                                                       s[i+le:i+le+1] in ('', ' '):
            count += 1
    return count
Can you explain me the logic behind it?

Comment: @VedantGanjoo The condition there simply checks the value of sub-string of length 1 before and after the current `'bob'` found, if the the sub-string is either `''` or `' '`, then it is okay and we can increment count. The sub-string is going to be equal to `''` only at the start and end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

> the program still counts 'bob' in 'bobs'

It doesn't.

> Also this code always returns 0

This is because of your else clause.

```
        else:
            count = 0
```

You're resetting the count here. That's not what you want; if the next character isn't a space, you don't want to do anything at all. Remove the whole else clause.

You have an additional bug you haven't noticed. If `string` ends with `substring`, the following test:

```
        if string[i+len(substring)] == ' ':
```

will attempt to read past the end of the string and throw an `IndexError`. Try to solve this problem on your own first.

Comment: I been on this for 2 hrs now. I'm not able to figure it out.

Comment: No, I'm not able to do it.

Comment: Try to change the `range` term of your `for` loop

Comment: I added +1 to the range 'in range (len(string)+1)'. It's not working.